# Time span that can detect overlaps

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails and would like to be able to describe a "time span" including a start time and a duration (also including a date). I'd like to be able to easily test whether two time spans have any intersection. I imagine something like this:

```
d1 = TimeSpan.new("1-1-2014 10 AM", 1.hour)
d2 = TimeSpan.new("1-1-2014 10:30 AM", 1.hour + 30.minutes)
d3 = TimeSpan.new("1-1-2014 12:00 PM", 1.hour)
d1 | d2 # true
d2 | d3 # false
```

I'm new at this and haven't had much luck searching through the libraries -- does something like this already exist? If not, any hints on the best approach to writing the class are appreciated. Thanks!

### Update

Based on the answers below I came up with this:

```
require 'active_support/all'

class TimeSpan
  attr_accessor :start_time, :duration, :time_range
  def initialize(start_time, duration)
    @start_time = DateTime.parse(start_time)
    @duration = duration
    @time_range = (@start_time..@start_time + @duration)
  end
  def |(other)
    @time_range.overlaps? other.time_range
  end
end


d1 = TimeSpan.new("1-1-2014 10 AM", 1.hour)
d2 = TimeSpan.new("1-1-2014 10:30 AM", 1.hour + 30.minutes)
d3 = TimeSpan.new("1-1-2014 12:01 PM", 1.hour)
p d1 | d2 # true
p d2 | d3 # false
```

Any further improvements are appreciated. One thing I'm considering is whether to subtract a minute from @time_range, so that there isn't an overlap from for example, 10 AM + 2.hours and 12 PM + 1.hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` ranges and `ActiveSupport`'s [`Range#overlaps?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Range.html#method-i-overlaps-3F) method:

```
t1 = DateTime.parse("1-1-2014 12:00 AM") #=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 10:00:00 +0000
d1 = (t1..t1+1.hour)                     #=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 10:00:00 +0000..Wed, 01 Jan 2014 11:00:00 +0000

t2 = DateTime.parse("1-1-2014 10:30 AM") #=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 10:30:00 +0000
d2 = (t2..t2+1.hour+30.minutes)          #=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 10:30:00 +0000..Wed, 01 Jan 2014 12:00:00 +0000

t3 = DateTime.parse("1-1-2014 12:00 PM") #=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 12:00:00 +0000
d3 = (t3..t3+1.hour)                     #=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 12:00:00 +0000..Wed, 01 Jan 2014 13:00:00 +0000

d1.overlaps? d2  #=> true
d1.overlaps? d3  #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Range has a method `cover` that should do what you need.

```
early_date = Time.now
later_date = early_date + 1.hour
middle_date = early_date + 30.minutes
outer_date = later_date + 1.minute

range = early_date..later_date
range.cover?(later_date) # true
range.cover?(outer_date) # false
```